# CCMenu doesnt work in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating an universal application and my CCMenu appears just fine on both iPhone, iPhone 4 and iPad. However the buttons do nothing when touched on the iPad.

I have no specific iPad code other than modifying the contentScaling property so that the iPad uses the same images as the iPhone 4. This means that the same images work on iPhone 4 but not on the iPad.

I am using cocos2d 0.99.rc0 and the iOS 4.1 SDK. I don't even know where to start troubleshooting this.

The only oddity i noticed recently is that the iPad seems to draw the menu scene once, then quickly redraws it for some reason, moving everything one pixel or something. My menu class is very simple and has no "refreshing" code or anything that is supposed to move. This doesnt happen on either low or high res iPhones.

Here is my code, sloppy but yet very simple.

MainMenu.m:

```
    CCMenuItemImage * playItem = [self makeMenuButtonWithSprite:@"Play.png" withSelector:@selector(play:)];

    CCMenuItemImage * resumeItem = [self makeMenuButtonWithSprite:@"Resume.png" withSelector:@selector(resume:)];

    CCMenuItemImage * optionsItem = [self makeMenuButtonWithSprite:@"Options.png" withSelector:@selector(options:)];

    CCMenuItemImage * helpItem = [self makeMenuButtonWithSprite:@"Help.png" withSelector:@selector(help:)];

    CCMenu *myMenu;

    // Check if there is a valid savegame by comparing versions.
    if ([[uD stringForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] isEqualToString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]] ) {
        myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:playItem, resumeItem, optionsItem, helpItem, nil];
    } else {
        myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:playItem, optionsItem, helpItem, nil];
    }

    // Arrange the menu items vertically
    [myMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:0.0f];
    myMenu.position = ccp(dB.wWidth/2,dB.wHeight/2);

    // add the menu to your scene
    [self addChild:myMenu z:100];
```

And the CCMenuItemImage factory:

```
- (CCMenuItemImage *)makeMenuButtonWithSprite:(NSString *)spriteFileName withSelector:(SEL)selector {
    CCSprite *spriteForButton = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:spriteFileName];
    spriteForButton.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f,0.5f);
    CCMenuItemImage * buttonImage =[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button.png"
                                                      selectedImage: @"button.png"
                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:selector];
    [buttonImage addChild:spriteForButton z:100];
    spriteForButton.position = ccp([buttonImage boundingBox].size.width/2,([buttonImage boundingBox].size.height/2)-5);
    return buttonImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found. This was related to my custom hack to make the iPad load retina graphics. The problem was in my appDelegate where i set the contentScaleFactor which made ccDirector scale and UIScreen scale mismatch.

Problem boiled down to graphics being big but cocos2d thinking that coordinates are low res.

Comment: Did you make hi-res images work ? If yes - please post the answer how to do it

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that any known bug exists for this issue. Not sure how to debug this without seeing any code, but, if it helps, here's some code of mine that successfully adds a menu using cocos2d 0.99.5, on iOS 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2 (no difference when I upgraded):

```
-(void) initBottomMenu {
CCMenuItem *aboutButton = [self gameButtonWithName:@"about" selector:@selector(onAbout:)];
CCMenuItem *settingsButton = [self gameButtonWithName:@"settings" selector:@selector(onSettings:)];
CCMenuItem *tutButton = [self gameButtonWithName:@"tutorial" selector:@selector(onTutorial:)];

CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:aboutButton, settingsButton, tutButton, nil];
menu.position = ccp(xPos, yPos);

[menu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:45.0];

[self addChild:menu];
}
```

The gameButtonWithName:selector: method looks like this:

```
-(CCMenuItem *) gameButtonWithName:(NSString *)name selector:(SEL)s {

NSString *iPadSuffix = @"IPad";

NSString *normal    = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@Btn%@.png", name, iPadSuffix, nil]   ;
NSString *selected  = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@Btn%@.png", name, iPadSuffix, nil];

CCMenuItem *retButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:normal
                                               selectedImage:selected
                                               disabledImage:selected
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:s];

[selected release];
[normal release];

return retButton;
}
```

sort of sloppy, but it works out well for adding a menu to my main scene.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have now added my own code to the original post - looks pretty much the same as yours yet it doesn't work.

Comment: On a side note, couldn't your create yours strings with [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@Btn%@.png", name, iPadSuffix, nil]; and then skip the whole release thing? I think that all objects created with the convenience-methods (ie not [[obj alloc] init]) are autoreleased, isnt that the case?

Comment: yeah, that's definitely true, but it's best practices to take care of as many allocs and releases as possible this way. There's no knowing when the iPhone will decide to rip through and release objects created with convenience methods -- this way I know when it happens. Once iPhone gets proper garbage collection, none of this will be an issue!

Comment: what happens when you take away the z calls? Also, if you haven't done this already, try putting NSLog("Button Pressed"); calls inside the selectors you're hitting with these buttons, and see if you're at least receiving touches. The image is the same, so you won't be able to tell visually, of course.

Comment: Ok, i removed all z calls both from the Menu and the Factory and i added an NSLog(@"play:"); line in the play: method. Turns out the method never gets called, like the menu is missing the touches or something.

Comment: I had a problem like this once; turned out the issue was that I was overriding onEnter:, and never calling super. Sort of a shot in the dark, but here's to hoping that this lends some insight.

Comment: Checked that just a moment ago, i'm not overriding anyting other than the default stuff. I basically took the HelloWorld Scene and stuck a menu to it. I also tried throwing the user straight to my GameScene, then i clicked pause (not a menu but a CGRectContainsPoint which works) to get me to the pause menu, the pause menu buttons didnt work either.

I also tried making a vanilla button without any text label or using my button factory, that one didnt react either. VERY fishy stuff going on.

Comment: VERY fishy. If you upload this sample project to github, or zip it and send it to me at sritchie09@gmail.com, I'll be happy to take a look. We can get to the bottom of this for sure.